# why hackers can decrypt my encrypted Connection String in web.config(C#)

Tags: asp.net

My application is on the shared Hosting.I've encrypted my Connection String programmatically to make it secure. However, the hacker still is able to decrypt the encrpted Connection String adding scripts into the DB.
Just wondering if there is a way to solve this problem? Many thanks !!!

Comment: Do you know if the hacker has access to the DLL's generated by the .net code ?

Comment: How can "the hacker" access your web.config?

Comment: Is it a shared database instance? Are you sure they don't just know the root password on your database?

Comment: More likely you're being attacked by Little Bobby Tables.

Answer (score 1):

[.NET vulnerability discovered last September.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/18/important-asp-net-security-vulnerability.aspx)

Make sure your .NET is up to date!

Answer (score 0):

If the hacker gains control over your server, he can do anything your code can do. Can your code decrypt the Connection String? (apparently yes) Then he can do it, too.